# Excel: if cell in column A = text1 and cell in column B = text2 then cell in column C = text3

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm desperately trying to figure out how to create a formula.  In column F, I've created a data list of 5 items. In column H, I've created another data list of 5 items. In column I, I'm trying to make another list of text options that will correspond to different combinations.

Here's what I'm trying to do: Per row, if cell in column F = textA, AND cell in column H = textB,  then cell in column I = textC. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `=IF(AND(F1="textA",H1="textB"),"textC","")` ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you please provide some sample data? It's unclear what you mean by "correspond to different combinations" and how "textC" relates to this. I have a feeling you want something different than `=IF(AND(F1="textA",H1="textB"),"textC","")` in `I1`, but that's how your question reads as is. Please [edit](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/236396) your question to make sure you get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(AND(A1="foo",B1="bar"),"true","false")`

If cell A1 contains the text "foo" and B1 contains "bar" C1 returns "true" else it returns "false"

Specific to your example;

`=IF(AND(F1="textA",H1="textB"),"textC","")` then copy down as many rows as you need.